# C++ Makefile 3 files

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a makefile problem. I know how to create a makefile for two, but not four different files including header files...

There are four files, main.cpp Dictionary.h Dictionary.cpp and Cinco.h

```
Cincotest: main.o Cinco.o
    g++ -o p3 main.o Cinco.o

main.o: main.cpp Cinco.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

Dictionary.o: Dictionary.cpp Dictionary.h
    g++ -c .cpp


# clean up
clean:
    rm -f p4 *.o *~
```

Do we need the other files code or could we get help here??

If you know the answer and could input the new code that would be perfect ;)

Comment: what about https://github.com/bronson/makefile-death ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like a fairly standard way of organizing code - `.cpp` and a `.h` header file to go with it.

The rules that you have are sufficient. Unless your `main.cpp` also #include-s the `Dictionary.h` header file, or your `dictionary.cpp` also #include-s the `Cinco.h`, in which case:

```
main.o: main.cpp Cinco.h Dictionary.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

Dictionary.o: Dictionary.cpp Cinco.h Dictionary.h
    g++ -c .cpp
```

A `makefile` is just a dependency list. For each `*.o` file, it's dependencies are all the source files needed to compile it. If in your `main.cpp` you #include `Dictionary.h`, then a change to `Dictionary.h` means that `main.cpp` needs to be recompiled, of course. Therefore, your dependency rule would indicate the same way.

Since you're using `g++`, you can also use `g++` to write your dependency rules for you. Try:

```
g++ -MM -MF main.deps main.cpp
```

See `gcc`'s man page for more information.